# SwiftUI: stuck on infinite page view implementation

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, uipageviewcontroller, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to create a PageView in pure SwiftUI. There's my test code below. And everything works as expected but the DragGesture. It just doesn't call 'onEnded' function. Never. How can I fix it?

```
struct PageView<V: View>: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var content: V
}

struct InfinitePageView: View {
    @State private var pages: [PageView] = [
        PageView(content: Text("Page")),
        PageView(content: Text("Page")),
        PageView(content: Text("Page"))
    ]
    
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int = 1
    @State private var isDragging: Bool = false
    
    private var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { _ in
                self.isDragging = true
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                self.isDragging = false
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                    resolvePages()
                }
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
                ForEach(pages) { page in
                    page.content
                        .tag(pages.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == page.id })!)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .gesture(drag)
            .onChange(of: selectedIndex, perform: { value in
                guard !isDragging else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    resolvePages()
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    private func resolvePages() {
        if selectedIndex > 1 {
            addNextPage()
        }
        if selectedIndex < 1 {
            addPreviousPage()
        }
    }
    
    private func addNextPage() {
        pages.append(PageView(content: Text("Page")))
        pages.removeFirst()
        selectedIndex = 1
    }
    
    private func addPreviousPage() {
        pages.insert(PageView(content: Text("Page")), at: 0)
        pages.removeLast()
        selectedIndex = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question, but I was trying to do a similar thing and ended up using the infinite carousel in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fB5MzDD1PZI&feature=emb_title). He included a link to the source code in the description, which is pure SwiftUI (using ZStack/Offset/Animation). You could probably update the code pretty easily to make it a full screen pager.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with SwiftUI

the `DragGesture` that you setup likely gets overridden by the `DragGesture` within the `TabView`.

Can detect `onEnded` with the setup in this post [Detect DragGesture cancelation in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807357/detect-draggesture-cancelation-in-swiftui) but that deactivates the `TabView`/Page gestures.

Your `onChange` code for `selectedIndex` runs once the new page is selected and would act should act the same as `onEnded`.

Comment: The problem is that if I change the pages array state variable while dragging continuous then TabView reloads immediately with no finishing scroll to page animation.

Comment: Good point that is probably that Gesture that overrides your `DragGesture`. Because of the inherent nature of SwiftUI (So much is automated) there are tradeoffs. Apple has SwiftUI tutorials and one of them has a "manual" PageView you might get more flexibility with that one. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit but if you need more you might have to create your own (Does not use the features of `TabView`)

Comment: Yep, I guess there's no other way but to use UIKit's UPageViewController wrapper. Just tried to complete the task with pure SwiftUI.

Comment: Looks like, the TabView with PageTabViewStyle uses some private class named _UIPageSheetPresentationController. Couldn't even get any result with Introspect framework :(