# SwiftUI Drag Gesture Cancel State

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, drag, draggesture

I made a view to drag left and right in SwiftUI. This is working fine but having an issue when dragging quickly.

I made a **Tinder** like swipe in my SwiftUI app. When I tries to quickly drag the view left and right the view stucks there. I am attaching video :

[image: video]

I do a little bit of **debugging** and came to know that sometimes when I quickly try to drag the view only **.onChange** state is working, **.onEnded** never gets called. This happens only if I have my View in **ScrollView**. If there is **no ScrollView**, then it works perfectly fine.

This is my code:

```
struct SwipeCard : View {

   @State var offset : CGFloat = 0
   @GestureState var isDragging = false

   var body: some View {

     ScrollView{
         MyView()
      }
      .cornerRadius(20)
      .offset(x: offset)
      .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: getRotation(angle: 30)))
      .contentShape(RoundedCorner(radius: 20, corners: .allCorners))
      .gesture(
                
             DragGesture()
                 .updating($isDragging, body: { value, out, _ in

                     out = true
                 })
                 .onChanged({ value in

                     let translation = value.translation.width
                     offset = (isDragging ? translation : .zero)

                     if translation > -15 && translation < 15 {
                         withAnimation {
 
                             offset = .zero
                         }
                     }
                 })
                 .onEnded({ value in
         
                     print("drag gesture reaches on ended state")
                     // rest of the logic
                 })
       )
   }
}
```

I want that it should not stuck in the midway, it should make the offset to **.zero**. How can I achieve this?

I searched this issue a lot but nothing worked in my case.

I had tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807357/detect-draggesture-cancelation-in-swiftui) solution but it is not working in my case.